# React Native iOS Push Notification with Image

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I currently have an app which was made with React Native. I need to display a local push notification, and there needs to be an image displayed within this notification. Currently, I am using the [`react-native-push-notification`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library for basic text notifications.

I have been looking for solutions but I have not found any way yet that I can add images into a notification. Is there some way to hook into native code that would allow me to do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) and it works great for me. It has an option for local notifications.

You can learn more about iOS notification with an image here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/notifications/reference/IOSNotification It gives an option to set a `launchImage` for iOS notifications. You should go through the documentation properly in order to install it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm), which is implemented using react-native-firebase. The support for issues are good enough and the document is well drafted for both ios and android. The pictures, icons and actions are configurable for both local and remote notifications.

Comment: this repository is not in development anymore and few feature might not work properly. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase , this is the ideal one for now